# How to ask a truth seeking question in a non-truth seeking question way?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've been pondering how to approach a question regarding reincarnation in the bible.  In some religions, reincarnation is the process where the spirit exists eternally.  When the spirit begins a "human experience" all memories are lost.  When the human experience ends (at death) the spirit returns and the process can happen again and again - with various out comes depending on tradition.

Let me be clear, I do not subscribe to reincarnation.  However I fell into a perplexing question.  Jesus was the logos, who existed since the beginning.  When the *incarnation of the logos* occured, it's obvious the Jesus "forgot" that he was God - which he then discovered later on in life before the cruxificion.  When he died, his spirit didn't die, it returned to "heaven" and at some point he will reincarnate again for the second comming.

This sounds an aweful lot like eastern religions version of reincarnation.  However I do not know how to phrase a question as to research this area w/o coming across as a truth seeking question.  I'm really just looking for material to read to research.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forget the resurrection? Jesus came back to life in his original body. I believe that most Christians think that is the body he will have forever. The idea that Jesus would be reincarnated a second time is not Biblical at all.

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't believe that everyone would agree with you.  I'm not saying that I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of reincarnation in Christianity has already been addressed. You may find my answer to this question enlightening: [Do any denominations believe in reincarnation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18378/do-any-denominations-believe-in-reincarnation/18414#18414)

Basically, there have been many denominations that believe in reincarnation, but throughout the ages, these denominations are typically labelled heretical and persecuted. Now, the non-persecuted Christians procreate their offspring, and this is why you get only a minority of Christians that actually believe in reincarnation today.

You are welcome to ask any question regarding a denomination's stance on reincarnation. But inquiries that talk about whether or not reincarnation is "true" or "correct" would be considered off-topic for this medium. In your case, you are interested in finding any support of Reincarnation in the Bible. The problem is, the Bible itself is a text. Any interpretation of the text is just that - an interpretation.

Comment: Agreed, however I would be interested in answers to such a question - specifically who the answers quote as to read those books.  Asking this directly would be a polling type question.

Comment: @TheFreemason You could just ask for a denominational support for the doctrine of reincarnation. I've listed a couple of groups, even though such of them are long gone and dead. You may not have a representative from those denominations answer your question, but then you probably don't need one anyway as long as the answer itself is accurate enough, regardless of who writes it.